# use DataTable to populate DataGridView in C# get extremely slow

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

I'm new to C#, and trying to use a DataGridView to display some data generated on the back end. It took about two minutes to even populate three rows. I referred to the tutorial on msdn and some other sources. And here is part of the code:

```
public partial class OrderBook : Form
{
    private static DataTable order_dt = new DataTable();

    public OrderBook()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // columns in the DataTable
        order_dt.Columns.Add("c1", typeof(string));
        order_dt.Columns.Add("c2", typeof(string));
        order_dt.Columns.Add("c3", typeof(int));
        order_dt.Columns.Add("c4", typeof(string));
        order_dt.Columns.Add("c5", typeof(int));
        order_dt.Columns.Add("c6", typeof(string));
        order_dt.Columns.Add("c7", typeof(int));
        order_dt.Columns.Add("c8", typeof(int));

        dgvOrderPanel.DataSource = order_dt; //dgvOrderPanel is the 
                                             //DataGridView component
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvc in dgvOrderPanel.Columns)
            dgvc.Width = 65;
    }

    // add a new row to the DataTable on each call
    public static void addRow(string order_info)
    {
        string[] fields = order_info.Split(' ');

        order_dt.Rows.Add(fields[0], fields[1], int.Parse(fields[2]), fields[3],
                          int.Parse(fields[4]), fields[5], int.Parse(fields[6]), 
                          int.Parse(fields[7]));
    }
    // the CellFormatting handler to determine the color of the row
    private void dgvOrderPanel_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvOrderPanel.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["c2"].Value.Equals("B"))
        {
            dgvOrderPanel.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        else
        {
            dgvOrderPanel.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
    // other methods...
}
```

Whenever the backend send a string containing the order_info to the front end via a socket, addRow() will be called. Each order_info corresponding to a single row in the DataTable, and the DataGridView.

The whole process is executed in the same thread. Any thought about why this is so slow? Any advise is appreciated!

Comment: There is nothing in the code that can produce such behavior. Could you provide more code and from where you are calling the method addRow?

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic Thank you for the quick reply. I updated the code, and explained when the addRow() gets called.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reply earlier, you didn't provided the code that calls the addRow method.